# Haskell As-patterns, binding variables to constants

Tags: haskell

(This code doesn't make much sense, but I need this logic to work in my other complicated function):

```
import Data.List

elemIndex1 xss@(x:xs) = 
    if (x == ' ') 
    then (elemIndex x xss) 
    else (elemIndex1 xs)
```

So I want this function to give this:

```
elemIndex1 "qwe asd zxc"
Just 3
```

Instead it gives this:

```
elemIndex1 "qwe asd zxc"
Just 0
```

As I understand, at the else clause xss actually becomes xs.
So my question is: is there a possibility to bind the variable (x:xs) to a constant and to use this constant at any iteration?

Comment: The issue is in your recursive step, as you're not taking account of the fact that you know the space isn't at index 0. You just need `1 + elemIndex1 xs` instead. (The `then` clause should also just give `Just 0` directly, since that is what the result will always be.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you are expecting `xss@(x:xs)` to be the following:

- `xss`: the *original* string given to elemIndex1

  - `x`: the first character of an arbitrary call
  - `xs`: the rest of the characters of an arbitrary call

e.g. for your example when `x` first matches a space

```
xss = "qwe asd zxc"
x = ' '
xs = "asd zxe"
```

This is not how the pattern match works. `xss` is actually equal to `x:xs`, so in that example it would be `" asd zxc"`.

If you want to keep around the first call to a function, you can use a helper function called inside of the scope of the original function.

```hs
weirdElemIndex str = weirdElemIndex' str
  where
    weirdElemIndex' ""     = Nothing
    weirdElemIndex' (x:xs) =
      if x == ' ' 
        then elemIndex ' ' str
        else weirdElemIndex' xs
```

Note that the `str` I reference in the body of the helper function will be a constant in its invocation.

For what it’s worth, your contrived example seems to be equivalent to `elemIndex ' '` since it deals with the case where there is no space in the string by returning `Nothing`.

Comment: A few minor points. Indentation of the `if ...` looks wrong. Further, it would be nice to add a base case for `[]`, since right now `weirdElemIndex []` crashes. (I'd also use `... then elemIndex ' ' str else ...` to stress that `x` is a space, but that's a matter of personal taste.)

Comment: Ah good point, I just copied the OP’s code. I’ll edit that in.